# How to group by sub documents and get unique value of value field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is my database collection:

```
{"productId" : 1,
"isVariant": 1,
"isComplete" : 1,
"variantId" : 1,
"attributeSet" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Capacity",
            "value" : "500 GB",
            "id" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Form Factor",
            "value" : "5 inch",
            "id" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 5,
            "name" : "Memory Components",
            "value" : "3D NAND",
            "isVariation" : 0
        }
    ]
},
{"productId" : 2,
"isVariant": 1,
"isComplete" : 1,
"variantId" : 1,
"attributeSet" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Capacity",
            "value" : "1 TB",
            "id" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Form Factor",
            "value" : "5 inch",
            "id" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 5,
            "name" : "Memory Components",
            "value" : "3D NAND",
            "isVariation" : 0
        }
    ]
},
{"productId" : 3,
"isVariant": 1,
"isComplete" : 0,
"variantId" : 1,
"attributeSet" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Capacity",
            "value" : "500 GB",
            "id" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Form Factor",
            "value" : "2.5 inch",
            "id" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 5,
            "name" : "Memory Components",
            "value" : "3D NAND",
            "isVariation" : 0
        }
    ]
},
{"productId" : 4,
"isVariant": 1,
"isComplete" : 0,
"variantId" : 1,
"attributeSet" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Capacity",
            "value" : "1 TB",
            "id" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Form Factor",
            "value" : "2.5 inch",
            "id" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 5,
            "name" : "Memory Components",
            "value" : "3D NAND",
            "isVariation" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to send the data of only the attribute where `isVariation` is not 0. Also I want to send the variant values of each attribute where `isComplete =1`. Hence the result should look like this

```
 result : [{
     "id": 3,
     "name": "Capacity",
     "value": [
         "500 GB",
         "1 TB"
     ]
  }, {
     "id": 4,
     "name": "Form Factor",
     "value": [
         "5 inch"
      ]
}]
```

The above result does not have value of 2.5 inch as the `isComplete` is 0 for this document. Can anyone help me with the query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDb querying documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65507080/mongodb-querying-documents)

Comment: Nope it doesn't

Comment: @VishalKumar make sure your question title should be meaningful and that brief your question, for details see [How do I ask a good question?
](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` `isComplete` is 1
- `$project` to show required fields
- `$unwind` deconstruct `attributeSet` array
- `$match` `attributeSet.isVariation` is not 0
- `$group` by `attributeSet.id` and get first `name` and get unique `value` using `$addToSet`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { isComplete: 1 } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      attributeSet: 1
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$attributeSet" },
  { $match: { "attributeSet.isVariation": { $ne: 0 } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$attributeSet.id",
      name: { $first: "$attributeSet.name"  },
      value: { $addToSet: "$attributeSet.value" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nNS1J0hiUEy)

> The $project stage is not required in your query, i have added because this will optimize your query performance.